# Continuous functions and converging sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\{ x_n\}$ is a sequence in $(a,b)$, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Is it true or false?

> > I think this is false but I am not sure of an example that would show it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true.  We know since $[a,b]$ is sequentially compact (do you know why?), every sequence has a convergent subsequence.  But then since $\{x_{n} \} \subseteq (a,b) \subseteq [a,b]$, it follows that $x_{n}$ has a subsequence that converges in $[a,b]$.

But since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, we know for each $x \in [a,b]$, given a sequence $\{ t_{n} \} \subseteq [a,b]$ such that $t_{n} \to x$, we have $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(t_{n}) = f(x)$.

But then if we call our convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}_{k = 1}^{\infty}$ from the original sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, since this sequence converges in $[a,b]$, call its limit $l$.  Then since $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} x_{n_{k}} = l$, and $f$ is defined and continuous at $l$, it follows that $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_{k}}) = f(l)$, which means a convergent subsequence of $\{f(x_{n}) \}$ is actually $\{ f(x_{n_{k}}) \}_{k = 1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I wonder why I thought it was false in the first place, haha...

Comment: @1---011 You're welcome!  It looks like you haven't accepted any answers for any of the questions you've asked on this site.  If you receive a response that answers your question in a way you deem satisfactory, you should "accept" the response by clicking the check mark next to it.  You can only accept one answer in each question that you ask.  If other users see that you don't accept any answers to your questions, they will be reluctant to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know. I am new to this haha :P

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $[a,b]$ is compact.
- $f$ is continuous, so $f([a,b])$ is compact.
- $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a sequence in $f([a,b])$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}$ converging to some $X \in [a,b]$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, the subsequence $\{ f(x_{n_k}) \}$ converges to $f(X)$.